# How to trim spaces when using a bulk insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I'm using a bulk insert to import an rpt file but I'm getting these errors :

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I think this is due to spaces between file columns, is there any way I can trim these spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: I think rpt stands for a report output file and this output is looking like a Fixed Width Data or System Data Format (SDF) data. Is there a chance that you can use C# for this job? It would be easy with C# (or any other language) to parse the column names from the first line, and determine widths fromdashes on second line to generate a datatable or a reader that you can use to insert data into SQL server (probably using SqlBulkCopy class). I have never found SQL server itself to be intuitive in importing text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only spaces in your file, your file format is fixed with and you will need a format file to load it.

```
SELECT *
  FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Extractions\F0005.rpt',
  FORMATFILE='C:\myTestSkipField.fmt'  
   ) AS t1;
```

I have included an example `.fmt` file below mapping the first few fields in your file using `EmptyField` columns to map the space. You could just omit this, as it looks like you will have to trim your fields anyway using `LTRIM(TRIM([column]))`

```
9.0
8
1     SQLCHAR     0     4     ""      1     DRSY        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2     SQLCHAR     0     1     ""      2     Empty1      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3     SQLCHAR     0     4     ""      3     DRTT        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4     SQLCHAR     0     10     ""     4     DRKY        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5     SQLCHAR     0     1     ""      5     Empty2      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
6     SQLCHAR     0     30     ""     6     DRDL01      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7     SQLCHAR     0     1     ""      7     Empty3      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8     SQLCHAR     0     1024    "\n"  8     Remainder   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

From the Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx), this is the file format of a `.fmt` file:

[image]

Comment: I will try and reproduce the problem. Is your `.rpt` file tab delimited or pipe delimted ?

Comment: What shoud myTestSkipField.fmt contain?